# How useful is the darkstalker feat outside of combat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, stealth

I understand how good the Darkstalker feat is in combat, and for melee characters it's basically required. But can the same be said for ranged characters and stealth out of combat? How useful is it then?

Answer (score 3):

Darkstalker is necessary if you need to sneak around things that have special senses that would otherwise auto-detect you. It’s pointless if you don’t need to do that. This is true both in combat and out: whether you’re sneaking up on something to stab it or sneaking past it to get whatever it’s guarding, you need Darkstalker if it has special senses.

Comment: In that case would level 12 be a good level to get it?

Comment: @Masakan That depends a lot on your campaign. Scent is common enough even from 1st that you could make use of it at any level if the campaign features the right things to sneak past, but depending on what you’re trying to sneak around, it may not be necessary until later, or even never.

Comment: There are also senses from which darkstalker does not protect one, so be careful about that.

Comment: @nijineko That is a debatable point. Darkstalker protects against most senses, and the implication (to me, anyway) is that any left out were oversights and/or stem from being found in independent supplements. And since the feat is a pure tax to avoid having your skill points go entirely to waste, it seems like it should just *work*. Force those with special senses to actually have to go to the effort of using them.

Comment: Mind sense and Life sense are the two most common bypasses. Though I see your point.